# Discord.py schedule based on sqlite3 database times

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im working on a question of the day discord bot. Right now I have a schedule where it will push a message to all the discords the bots in at 11 am, daily. That works great however, I would like to make it so guilds can choose their own times the question will be posted (to cut back on the load being pushed to discord all at once).

I use SQLite3 database to store information on guilds and I would like to figure out how to check the times in the database, if that time matches, post that question (*more focused on the schedule aspect than getting the information from the database to bot*).

I was thinking about `@tasks.loop()` and having it check the database every x minutes but I can't think of a way to make sure it doesn't double post as I would like to rely just on the hour, not the minutes or seconds and still keep a 24-hour schedule.

Comment: Please include enough details to answer the question: How are you reading from the database?

Comment: in database for every guild you could keep `date` when you send last message for this guild and check it before sending new message to guild. And after sending new message you would have to update `date` in database

Comment: you can use code to create new `tasks`- so maybe for every guild you would have to create separated `tasks` with own time. I don't know if it gives some ID to update task when guild set different time (or delete task with old time and create new task with new time)